# Storing dates-time scales in a SQLite database table but in only one row

Tags: android, database, store

I'm trying to do one patient program for veterinary use. I'm creating a SQLite database table which includes patient name, owner name, address etc. But this table should include also when the patient should be made check-up, when it should be vaccinated, when it will take a surgery.(we can say a time scale)... Name, address etc are unique data's; there is only one name, only one address. But the "time scale" is not unique. It will store not only one data. What can I do now? Should I made a new database table for every patient to store these time scales? or should I store more than one data inside a one database row like using string arrays or something else? I think my best choice is storing a new database inside a database table row but is it possible?
Some help will be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this:

```
User_Schedule
-------------
create table user_schedule
(
   user_id integer,
   event_type text,
   event_date text // only because it's SQLite
)
```

This way every user can have n number of events and you can give each event a name so you could easily query for something like, "Give me all users that have a vaccination coming up soon."